# Why debugging by magento log, true property shows 1, false property shows nothing?

Tags: magento, debugging, logging

When I debugging by using magento log, the true property shows 1, false property shows nothing, simple example like below

```
$true = true;
$false = false;
Mage::log($true);
Mage::log($false);
```

The log shows:

```
2017-05-09T01:34:11+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2017-05-09T01:34:11+00:00 DEBUG (7):
```

I want to know the reason, why the log does not show 'true' and 'false'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) shows you why this is.

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.

If you want FALSE to show in the log you could do something like this:

```
Mage::log($true ? 'true value' : 'false value');
```